# При попытке добавить элемент в List возникает исключение

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Создал в отдельном классе List, чтобы использовать его в формах:

```
static class Data
{
    public static List<string> ToHide { get; set; }
}
```

При попытке записи в него значений из формы следующим образом:

```
CheckBox box = sender as CheckBox;

if (box.Checked)
{
    Data.ToHide.Add(box.Text);
}
```

возникает исключение "Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта". В чём может быть ошибка?

Comment: Необходимо создать объект List <string> ToHide. В конструкторе класса Data добавить ToHide=new List<string>()

Comment: Либо сделать поле класса private static List<string> toHide=new List<string>() ; а дальше свойство: public static List<string> ToHide { get{return toHide;} {set {toHide=value;} }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибка в том, что вы ссылаетесь на статическое свойство `ToHide` класса `Data`, которое не было инициализировано. Т.е. ссылка свойства указывает на `null` и отсюда ожидаемый NullReferenceException. Как заметили в комментариях к вопросу - самый очевидный вариант инициализировать свойство в конструкторе:

```
static class Data
{
    public static List<string> ToHide { get; set; }
    public Data()
    {
        ToHide = new List<string>();
    }
}
```

Но в вашем случае класс `Data` помечен модификатором statiс и не может иметь конструкторов, поэтому добавьте в строке объявления инициализацию автосвойств:

```
static class Data
{
    public static List<string> ToHide { get; set; } = new List<string>();
}
```